# Grabbing the latest 3 records from model rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Just wondering if there is a more efficient way of handling the following query, within my controller i have

```
@latest = Portfolio.limit(3).order('taken desc')
```

to extract the latest 3 records from my model.

Is there a more efficient query that could handle this, would the query be better served within a scope in the model?

Advice appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work fine

```
class Portfolio < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :last_three_taken, -> { order('taken desc').limit(3) }
end
```

This would make your controller more indipendent from the database logic:

```
@latest = Portfolio.last_three_taken
```

So, it wouldn't be a much more efficient from a performance point of view, but it gains a much better MVC separation in my opinion.